# Piecewise / Noncontiguous Ranges?

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

Is there any kind of object class for piecewise / noncontiguous ranges in Julia?  For instance, I can create a regular range:

```
a = UnitRange(1:5)
```

But, if I wanted to combine this with other ranges:

```
b = UnitRange([1:5, 8:10, 4:7])
```

I cannot currently find an object or method.  There is a PiecewiseIncreasingRanges module (https://github.com/simonster/PiecewiseIncreasingRanges.jl) that would be just what I want in this situation, except that it, as the name implies, requires the ranges be monotonically increasing.

The context for this is that I am looking for a way to create a compressed, memory efficient version of the SparseMatrixCSC type for sparse matrices with repeating rows.  The RLEVectors module will work well to save space on the nonzerovalue vector in the sparse matrix class.  Now though I am trying to find something to save space for the rowvalue vector that also defines the sparse matrix, since series of repeating rows will result in ranges of values in that vector (e.g. if the first 10 rows, or even certain columns in the first ten rows, of a sparse matrix are identical, then there will be a lot of 1:10 patterns in the row value vector).

More generally, I'd like a range such as the b object that I try to create above over which I could do an iterated loop, getting:

```
for (idx, item) in enumerate(hypothetical_object)
    println("idx: $idx, item: $item")
end

idx: 1, item: 1
idx: 2, item: 2
...
idx: 5, item: 5
idx: 6, item: 8
idx: 7, item: 9
idx: 8, item: 10
idx: 9, item: 4
idx: 10, item: 5
...
```

Update: One thing I'm considering, and will probably try implementing if I don't hear other suggestions here, will be to just create an array of PiecewiseIncreasingRange objects, one for each column in my sparse matrix.  (I would probably also then break the nonzero value vector into an array of separate pieces, one for each column of my sparse matrix as well).  This would at least be relatively simple to implement.  I don't have a good sense off the bat how this would compare in terms of computational efficiency to the kind of object I am searching for in this question.  I suspect that memory requirements would be about the same.

Comment: Sounds like a good new `Type` which could be added to Julia. Possible names: `CompressedSet`, `RangeSet`. Maybe other commenters will have better names.

Comment: Just for your initial question, can't you use an array of ranges?

Comment: @rcpinto I'm not certain.  The thing is that I'd like to be able to query this object like a normal range via the lookup method.  E.g. With a regular range, I can, for instance, enter (20:40)[5]  and get back 24, which is what I would want, and the functionality I was trying to describe in the loop illustration above.  With an array of ranges though, I at least couldn't see an obvious way to get that.  Using lookup on the array itself, for instance, would just give me a particular range.  One possibility would be to define a new method for such an array. But do you see a more direct way?

Comment: Nvm, what I was calling a range array is actually an Int array, because the ranges are converted in the process. I can do idx = [1:5; 8:10; 4:7] and idx[7] will give me 9, but idx stores all indices and I think you don't want that.

Comment: @rcpinto Precisely.  Yeah, the rub is to cut down on the space in memory while still being able to do the querying (also, along with the memory savings, and closely connected to it, in theory what I'm looking for should lead to faster querying.  E.g. I ran some tests on ranges of approximate length 1e8 or so, comparing the PiecewiseIncreasingRange objects to Int arrays.  Using PiecewiseIncreasingRange objects was much, much faster).  Thank you though for the suggestion!

Comment: This seems definitely like a situation in which you have to create your own type. Fortunately, you have the code in PiecewiseIncreasingRanges as a model to work from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop over a sequence of ranges (or other iterators), you can use the `chain` function in the [Iterators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl) package.

For example:

`using Iterators
b = chain(1:5, 8:10, 4:7)
for i in b
   println(i)
end`

outputs the elements of each range.